# Send JSON string (array) from Javascript to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, json, http-post

for hours I try to find a simple solution to send a ready JSON string to a PHP method.
Javascript part:

```
form = document.createElement("form"),
node = document.createElement("input");
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
form.method = "POST";
element1.value='[{"id": 110, "teamname": "first"}, {"id": 140, "teamname": "second"}]';
element1.name="teams";
form.appendChild(element1);  
form.appendChild(node.cloneNode());
form.action = "?updateTeamnames";
form.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

PHP:
If I echo the raw data with (echo file_get_contents('php://input');). I get this:

```
teams=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A+110%2C+%22teamname%22%3A+%22first%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+140%2C+%22teamname%22%3A+%22second%22%7D%5D
```

How can I access the JSON string teams?
I tried this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $data;
```

without success. I think $data is NULL.
I tried this:

```
echo $_POST['teams'];
```

which led me to this:

```
[{\“id\“: 110, \“teamname\“: \“first\“}, {\“id\“: 140, \“teamname\“: \“second\“}]
```

Which can't be used as string in json_decode.

The main problem is, that I don't know which part is wrong...
Thanks for helping

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery.ajax to send data?

Comment: if you put $_POST['teams']  on json_decode()  then its fixed the problem! why can't be used as string?

Comment: I did that. I wrote $object = json_decode($_POST['teams']);
Afterwards I trid to access a value. No success. 
As I sad: I don't know which part is wrong. Maybe just the access like $objec[0]->id, or $object[0]['id']...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax to post data as below:

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax('./?updateTeamnames', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {teams: [{id: 110, teamname: "first"}, {id: 140, teamname: "second"}]}
});
</script>
```

In PHP script, you can see your data by dump:

```
var_dump($_POST['teams']);
```

Comment: And how can I then access the id of the first element?

Comment: You can access id of first array element by using this: `$_POST['teams'][0]['id']`

Comment: Just figured out: The ajax doesn't work. I've never done anything with jQuery ajax.
I just copied the code into a function, but it never sends a post message.

Comment: Can you open the debug Console and please tell me what error has been occur?

Comment: You mean the console of Firefox?:
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1  jquery-migrate.min.js:2:542
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/  lpfulllib.js:7:160
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  intern

Comment: I think I know where the problem is: The website is hosted with WordPress...
Isn't there a way without ajax?